# Angular 4 Display Arabic Characters from right to left

Tags: html, angular, internationalization, left-to-right

In my angular app, i have to able to display Arabic character from Right to Left, i am able to display the Arabic characters, but not from right to left.

[image]

Is there something in Angular that when it detects Arabic language then it will automatically display from right to left, or i have to do the logic on my own (if locale is Arabic, then format from right to left, else, left to right). Or any other suggestions is welcome, never do i18n before so any recommendation is welcomed.

Comment: Use [ngClass]="{'arabic-text':isArabic}" in your parent `<div>` you can css `.arabic-text{direction:rtl}`;

Comment: you can also use html `dir` attribute. By default it is `auto`, meaning if your locale is arabic, it will display from right to left. Maybe [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/may/23/right-to-left-rtl-text-display-in-angular-and-aspnet) will help you?

Comment: @Chaitanya this will auto-detect arabic character and set the css text direction to rtl?

Comment: Then use the same class and instead of direction use `text-align:right`